# How do I replace a Font Awesome logo in this XenForo style?

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome, xenforo

I would like to change the font awesome-based logo in [this](http://www.audentio.com/preview/xenforo/intrepid) XenForo style.  The style has a specific setting for Glyph Logo Icon in the admin panel, the default value of which was fa fa-rocket.  When I change that value to, for example, fa fa-mars, the logo just disappears.  I don't see any references to fa fa-rocket in the imported templates (there was a file called font-awesome.min.css that got uploaded during the style's installation, but it's not in the list of editable templates)

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  This style used an outdated version of Font Awesome (4.1), which didn't include the icons I wanted.  I changed the Font Awesome path under Style Properties => Typography to the 4.3 CDN version, and everything loads now.